# Vector to final on RNAV approach with the Intermediate and final segments are not aligned

Tags: air-traffic-control, approach, rnav

Consider the RNAV 30 approach to C83 (Byron, CA),
[image: Plate]

On a recent training flight requesting vectors for the approach, ATC pointed us to the MOVDD IF before cutting us loose (informing us that we would be getting a vector to that fix). The segment between here and the FAF is 11 degrees off from the final segment. On a GTN650 at least (and I assume other similar Garmin devices), selecting “Vectors” as the approach method gives you the FAF line with your deviation from it & sequences from the FAF. This seems not correct for flying this particular approach. The best my CFI & I could come up with was to enter the approach as being flown from the IAF (SMONE) then select “Direct to MOVDD” sometime before reaching it (such as when ATC gives the last turn), after which the GPS will sequence to the intermediate-to-final segment. But this seems non-standard. What do others do in this situation?

Comment: I'm not a pilot, but it seems to me "Vectors" would be the wrong approach method if you're getting vectors to an IF rather than vectors to final approach course. When vectoring to an IF we can allow up to a 90º intercept, and you follow the approach course inbound on your own; when vectoring to final approach course there is a maximum 30º intercept.

Comment: @randomhead, I’m guessing you’re ATC? Why do you say vectors are the “wrong” approach method? In this case it was equivalent to “cleared direct to MOVDD” from a point where the intercept angle was ~90 degrees, so maybe not meaningfully different. But anyway, the question was more about “buttonology” with the approach.

Comment: I can't speak to the buttonology but it seems my intuition was correct according to wbeard52's answer. The "Vectors" method would be used when you're getting guidance to final approach *course* which is different from being pointed at a *fix* and told to proceed on the approach course from the fix. I don't know the nitty-gritty details of the difference; perhaps something to do with when the sensitivity of the simulated LOC needle changes? Though it does sound like you would have the same issue if you actually were to receive vectors to the 311º final between MOVDD and BABPI.

Comment: Learn the difference between Activate Approach and Activate Vectors to Final. [HERE](https://bruceair.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/avoiding-the-vectors-to-final-scramble/) and [HERE](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2016/august/pilot/on-instruments) are two resources to get you started.

Comment: Not knowing the G650 (but I do know the G550, G1000 and G3000) what you would likely do is 1) From the Flightplan Page, select Direct to: MOVDD; 2) When appropriate (when cleared for the approach) select PROC a) ACTIVATE APPROACH (that is a single button on the G1000 and G3000...)

Comment: Selecting Activate Vectors to Final does something different. It draws a line from the TZ straight through the FAF and beyond. The unit 1) deletes all waypoints up to the FAF and 2) sets the shortest intercept of 90º or less. THERE IS NO TERRAIN CLEARANCE PROVIDED so that intercept might be through a mountain.

Comment: @dawg, I think it would be worth to write that as an answer.

Comment: What exactly were you cleared or instructed to do? "N12345, cleared direct MOVDD, cross MOVDD at or above 3000, cleared RNAV 30 approach", or "N12345, fly direct MOVDD, maintain at or above 3000, expect vectors to final", or something else?

Comment: @dawg - those are good links, especially the first one.

Comment: @Pondlife - The first. It appears that what my CFI and I did was the right thing, at least judging from some other tutorials I’ve found on line (following @dawg’s first link).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since most fatal accidents are [during approach](https://accidentstats.airbus.com/statistics/accident-by-flight-phase), it is important to maintain 100% compliance with the procedure and have a clear understanding of what your FMS will do with different modes.

There is an important Garmin / FMS distinction between:

1. Selecting "Activate Approach" mode when navigating to a fix leading to an approach sequence, and;
2. Navigating directly to the FAF via ATC vectors by selecting  "Vectors to Final" ("VTF") mode.

If you select Vectors to Final in G1000 or G3000 (likely similar to your G650), the following things happen (from memory, I may have missed a few):

1. The waypoints in the flight plan are bypassed (but remain inactive in the plan and available to re-navigate direct to) and the FAF is made active;
2. Approach mode is engaged (which increases needle sensitivity);
3. If you have a non-GPS approach loaded, the frequency for that approach is made active and the needles switch to the relevant indication (green needles for ILS for example);
4. If you are navigating to a GPS waypoint, the FMS turns off lateral guidance and engages roll-mode (if you are in Heading mode, that mode is maintained);
5. The HSI Bearing Needle is set to the final approach course (or outbound course for a back course approach);
6. A graphical magenta line representing an extension of the line between the touchdown zone and the FAF is drawn on the map.

It would be unusual to use VTF (in IFR conditions) without being under some form of ATC guidance on vectors and terrain clearance - Hence 'Vectors' to Final. The use for VTF mode is usually when the pilot receives a clearance as follows:

> **ATC:** N188L, six miles from BABPI, *turn right heading 280*, *maintain two thousand six hundred until established* on final approach course, *cleared RNAV runway 30 approach* Byron Airport.
> **Pilot:** Right turn 280, two thousand six hundred until established, cleared RNAV 30 approach, 88L.

(The italicized sections are meaningful; look them up in the [Pilot Controller Glossary](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/pcg_4-03-14.pdf))

At that point (assuming already at 2600), the pilot

1. Affirms the correct approach is loaded in the FMS flight plan;
2. Dials in 280º on the heading bug;
3. Engages heading mode, and;
4. selects Vectors to Final and the Garmin will then auto engage the approach from the FAF inbound. (Since this is a LPV approach, the Garmin will also intercept the vertical flight path.)

A contrary but common clearance might also be:

> **ATC:** N188L, *cleared direct MOVDD*, *cross MOVDD at or above* three thousand, *cleared RNAV runway 30 approach* Byron Airport.
> **Pilot:** Direct MOVDD, MOVDD at or above three thousand, cleared RNAV 30 approach, 88L.

In this case, there is a distinctly different FMS sequence:

1. Affirm the correct approach is loaded in the FMS flight plan;
2. Select MOVDD in the flight plan (this will be either an IAF or an IF);
3. Select Direct To - Enter - Enter to make active;
4. Select FMS mode (if not already selected and skipping the part to make sure the ship does not jump uncomfortably towards MOVDD);
5. Engage Approach Mode;
6. The Garmin will now auto sequence the approach including auto selecting green needles to fly an ILS or VOR if required. The Garmin will also intercept the vertical flight path if available.

You state in your question *ATC pointed us to the MOVDD IF before cutting us loose (informing us that we would be getting a vector to that fix)*

So what you do is:

1. Enter Direct To MOVDD and fly that course;
2. Select Activate Approach when you are cleared to fly that approach;
3. If ATC gives you a vector (perhaps because ATC does not want you to go straight there) then you enter heading mode and use the bug for that vector. Reset Direct To when ATC stops vectoring you.
4. Even if you receive a vector, you continue to have MOVDD as the active waypoint and you *do not* engage VTF *unless* you receive a clearance and a vector related to that clearance with the intent of you ending up on the final approach course near the FAF or *a linear extension of the final approach course.*

For illustration, consider the approach to KEGE (below, with the Vectors To Final magenta line drawn.

If you were to select VTF well outside of the IAF for this approach (and you were not under ATC POSITIVE CONTROL) there is a high risk that you would hit the 11,200 foot mountain just 7 miles from the FAF on the magenta line.

If VTF is engaged at a time when the pilot does not understand the sequence or limitations, [BAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Airlines_Flight_965) [THINGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_Air_Flight_801) [CAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asiana_Airlines_Flight_733) [HAPPEN!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_Airways_International_Flight_311) The FMS itself does not maintain terrain clearance for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for making clear the distinction between "vectors to final approach course" and "vectors to IAF/IF." OP's question, though, is what to do when the intermediate approach course they're being vectored to is not aligned with the actual final approach course to the runway. wbeard suggests dialing in a radial off a relevant fix (e.g. the 131º radial off BABPI or the 311º radial off MOVDD) and following that inbound to BABPI before actually selecting the "approach" to follow. Could you discuss that possibility in your answer?

Comment: Your current answer has the same problem as OP's question: If OP does actually receive vectors to the final (or rather, intermediate) approach course outside BABPI or MOVDD, they will be vectored to join a 314º/317º/311º course—but selecting "vector to final" will generate a 300º course to join instead.

Comment: @randomhead: If the expected vectors are not received to MOVVDD as expected, the pilot should clarify expectations with ATC. If the expected vectors are not received under actual IFR conditions, treat either rationally or as lost comm. It sounded actually as if this was a practice approach under VFR conditions and the controller became too busy to handle as expected (if I had to guess...)

Comment: @randomhead: Thanks for the edits btw. Useful!

Comment: I've read the answer carefully and I still don't see what OP should do if they receive vectors to **intermediate approach course**, i.e. the 311º or 317º course that is not in line with the 300º **final** approach course. This is not what happened, but hypothetically it could happen. If they engage VTF, will the GPS not draw a magenta line straight out at 300º, much as you show in your example at EGE? It would not be correct to follow that 300º course before reaching BABPI, so how should OP engage the system to intercept the correct intermediate course from the 280º ATC-assigned vector?

Comment: Is this an actual IFR approach or a VFR practice approach? It sounds like the later so ATC will not necessary vector in the same way for expediency. That is probably 90% of the problem here.  If this is an actual approach, ATC will either expect 1) the procedure to be flown as published (use the flight plan to do so) or 2) will issue vectors to an IAF (use the flight plan to navigate to that point) or 3) provide vectors to the final approach course with appropriate spacing outside the FAF. Only for number 3 would you use VTF.  Clear?

Comment: I am asking specifically about the third possibility: ATC provides vectors to the final approach course. But they will provide vectors to intercept the course *at least* three miles outside of BABPI, so the course to be intercepted is not the "final" approach course but an intermediate one. ATC will vector to a 30º intercept of the 311º course, and OP will intercept that course and fly to BABPI, turning left at BABPI to the 300º true final course. How will OP determine when they are established on the 311º course to BABPI? If they select VTF it sounds like they will *only* see the 300º course.

Comment: The segment from MOVDD to BABPI is **not** the final approach course; the extended line bearing 300º passing through BABPI and continuing on that same bearing is the final approach course. ATC *could* give a vector to intercept the final approach course (but they would need to specify that) and the intercept would be east of MOVDD. You would not be flying the 311º segment from MOVDD to BABPI and you would use VTF mode in this case. Or they could (more likely) specify a vector to MOVDD. You would use flight plan intercept in this case.

Comment: Hm. I don't have any non-aligned courses like that in my airspace but I fail to see any reason why ATC would not vector to the 311º course between MOVDD and BABPI. It's the thick black line depicted approach course segment outside the FAF. [P/CG *Final Approach Course*](https://123atc.com/term/final-approach-course)—A bearing/radial/track **of an instrument approach leading to a runway** or an extended runway centerline all without regard to distance.

Comment: But 311º segment does not fit that definition - a constant 311º would put you EAST of the runway. It is by any definition an [INTERMEDIATE APPROACH SEGMENT](https://123atc.com/term/intermediate-approach-segment-icao) I do not believe ATC would vector an intercept between MOVDD and BABPI for many reasons such as the turning area not being defined for that segment and most FMSs not engaging vertical path guidance outside the final approach course. It is certainly *possible* to use an FMS to intercept that segment but the spoken clearance would take more time than just  clearing direct to MOVDD.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124728/discussion-between-randomhead-and-dawg).

Comment: @dawg - This was an IFR approach, though conditions were VMC. There was significant weather in the area though, and the approach was pretty bumpy which made it extra exciting.

Comment: @FosterBoondoggle: If in actual conditions, and the clearance is unclear, ask ATC for clarification. You would program the FMS differently if you were expecting to engage the approach on an extend final, at an IF, or if the really want you to intercept a segment.

Answer (score 0):

You stated ATC indicated they will give you vectors to the IF and not vectors to final (VTF).  Why would you select VTF when that is not what ATC is doing?  It's a rhetorical question but hopefully designed to allow you to realize that VTF is, in my opinion, the non-standard method.

I have flown lots of different GPS/FMS installations.  They all have VTF feature.  Some called it activate approach while other call it VTF.  All of these will provide guidance to the final approach capture fix (FACF) which is typically the waypoint in front of the FAF.  Some approaches don't have an intermediate fix outside the FAF and those may have a computer navigational fix (CNF) that the GPS / FMS uses to align the final approach course.  All CNF waypoints are surrounded by square brackets [CFBTF] as depicted on KICT ILS 01L.  You will only see the CNF waypoint if you do not select a transition on the GPS / FMS.

Others approaches, like the one you mentioned have multiple waypoints outside the FAF.  In this case, you will not see any waypoints outside the FACF (in this case, MOVDD).  If you were vectored to one of those you will need to select SMONE as the transition and let the FMS / GPS auto-sequence after you pass it.

Comment: Seems like my slightly educated guess was correct (OP selected "vectors to final" when they did not, in fact, receive vectors to final). But supposing they **had** actually received vectors to the 311º or 317º final approach segments, what would be the proper way of programming the GPS?

Comment: On a garmin,  I would would go direct to a waypoint that is along the 311 or 317 track.  I would then hit the OBS button and select the 311 or 317 radial.  You will see the magenta line on the screen move to align with the CDI.  You can then visually see the intercept ATC is giving you.  At some point (I don't remember when) you will need to deselect OBS for the approach to sequence correctly.

Comment: If ATC provided the unlikely instruction of “Fly heading xyz; vector to the intermediate segment between MOVDD and BABPI,” I guess I’d highlight BABPI in the flight plan, hit menu, and select “activate leg.” But I highly doubt that was the instruction.

Comment: @eater, why would you doubt there could be an instruction to intercept the approach course outside of the FAF? It seems in OP's case there was not, they were vectored to the IF instead. But vectoring to join a course outside the FAF is not uncommon by any stretch of the imagination.